# Как заменить значение по фильтру js: map через filter

Tags: javascript

```
this.tiles.map((x) => [x]).filter(x => x !== deletedTile) = reopenTile;
```

Пробую так, но в блоке фильтра пишет:

> The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.

Пробую так:

```
this.tiles[this.tiles.map((x) => [x]).filter(x => x !== deletedTile)] = reopenTile;
```

Но выдает:

> Type 'TileData[][]' cannot be used as an index type.

Хочу заменить `deletedTile` на `reopenTile`. Что не так?

P.S. Отталкивался от такого решения:

```
var items = Array(523, 3452, 334, 31, 5346);

items[items.map((e, i) => [i, e]).filter(e => e[1] == 3452)[0][0]] = 1010
```

Comment: Первый вариант не может работать потому что и map и filter возвращают новый массив, который не записан ни в одну переменную и Вы пытаетесь этому анонимному массиву что то присвоить.

Второй вариант по идее может работать, но TileData в Вашем коде я не нашел. При этом чтобы это работало конструкция map.filter должна возвращать единственное значение, что неочевидно

Comment: this.tiles = это массив объектов типа TileData.

Comment: Приведите пример ваших данных. Что хранится в `this.tiles`, `reopenTile`?

Comment: предлагаю воспользоваться циклом =)

Comment: Да я хотел одним запросом )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// ┌ mocking 
function TileData(value) { this.value = value; }
const tiles = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'].map(v => new TileData(v)), 
      deletedTile = tiles[2],                  // { value: 't3' }
      reopenTile = new TileData('reopen');     // { value: 'reopen' }
// └ mocking

tiles.splice(tiles.findIndex(t => t === deletedTile), 1, reopenTile); 

console.log(tiles);
```

Первый аргумент - индекс (находим позицию *deletedTile* в массиве *tiles*): `tiles.findIndex(t => t === deletedTile)`,

Второй аргумент - количество удаляемых элементов: `1`,

Третий аргумент, и далее - вставляемые (начиная с того же индекса) элементы: только `reopenTile`.

[Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) на MDN

---

*<sub>**p.s.**: Значение `reopenTile` - объектного типа, а значит, оно передается **по ссылке**. Любые изменения этого значения через упомянутую переменную, отразятся и на значении в массиве `tiles`.

**p.p.s.**: Код в ответе наследует алгоритмический недостаток кода в вопросе - отсутствие проверки, есть ли вообще `deletedTile` в `tiles`.</sub>*

#### Дополнительно:

В случае когда `deletedTile` является ссылкой на объект в элементе массива `tiles` (как в примере), вместо `findIndex` лучше использовать более быстрый `indexOf`.

Вариант с проверкой наличия `deletedTile` в массиве `tiles`, через `if`:

```
let deletedTileIdx = tiles.indexOf(deletedTile);
if (deletedTileIdx === -1)
  deletedTileIdx = Infinity;
tiles.splice(deletedTileIdx, 1, reopenTile);
```

или, с использованием тернарного оператора:

```
const deletedTileIdx = tiles.indexOf(deletedTile);
tiles.splice(deletedTileIdx < 0 ? Infinity : deletedTileIdx, 1, reopenTile);
```

Здесь при отсутствии искомого объекта в массиве, мы передаем `Infinity` как индекс - чтобы `reopenTile` добавился в конец массива, независимо от его длины. Второй аргумент `splice` при этом не имеет эффекта (так как после последнего элемента массива, удалять нечего).

Comment: (+), но мне кажется это как раз тот случай когда не надо мудрить и воспользоваться циклом =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, Так метод `findIndex` и реализует цикл. Мудрить, в данном случае - это писать чисто императивный код (его возможное преимущество только в производительности, и акцентирую на слове *возможное*... во всем остальном, он будет хуже).

Comment: Почему тогда не `tiles[tiles.findIndex(t => t === deletedTile)] = reopenTile` ?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, Потому что в случае отсутствия `deletedTile` в массиве, `reopenTile` не будет добавлен (это плохо тем, что фактический результат противоречит семантике выражения), тогда как `splice` его добавит хоть как-то (в конец, и удалив последний элемент - что тоже совсем неок, но хотя бы предсказуемо). Я бы вообще сделал в три шага: занес результат (гораздо более скоростного) `indexOf` в переменную, проверил ее значение, и только затем добавлял бы `reopenTile`. Но вопрос предполагает ответ однострочным выражением... так что ограничился предупреждением в постпостскриптуме.

Comment: Можно было бы еще через тернарник решить, это да. Но он автора запутает, а мне за это минусов напихают.

Comment: yar85, напиши, плиз, вариант через тернарник как дополнение :)

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, готово. Два разных варианта проверки результата поиска (`=== -1` и `< 0`) идентичны, так как `indexOf` возвращает `-1` когда значение в массиве не найдено... это дело вкуса, кому как больше нравится (я предпочитаю `< 0`, т.к. вполне понятно что индекс не может быть отрицательным).